# How do you solve $a^2b^2c-8abc+c^2+ac+bc-ab+8c+8=0$?

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

What is the general solution inf $\mathbb{R}_+$ of $a^2b^2c-8abc+c^2+ac+bc-ab+8c+8=0$, where $0<ab<8$? I can see the trivial solution 2,2,2, but what is the easiest way to write down the general solution in the positive reals?

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions for $a,b,c$? Otherwise there will be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: For $a=b=c$ we have $(a^3 + 4a^2 + 4a + 2)(a - 2)=0$, which has $2$ real solutions, namely $a=2$ and $a=2.83928675521$. In general, we have infinitely many. For example, consider this as a quadratic equation in $c$ and find, which $a,b$ yields positive real solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This is by way of an extended comment to show one way of simplifying what you are given.

If you set $p=ab, q=a+b$ this becomes $c^2+(p^2-8p+q+8)c+(8-q)=0$ or $c^2+\left((p-4)^2+q-8\right)+8-q=0$

Now set $8-q=Q$ and $p-4=P$ to give $$c^2+(P^2-Q)c+Q=0$$

Now $-4\lt P\lt 4$, and this looks rather easier to analyse in the general case. If $P$ and $Q$ are known, $a$ and $b$ will themselves be the roots of a quadratic.

The general solution can thus be written in terms of $P$ and $Q$.